# background cover the whole screen only by background property?

Tags: css

if I write this in my css file.

```
html {
    background: black;
}
```

the black color will cover my whole screen. But at that time, my `html` Element doesn't have a real height.The `height` property is 0.

For another HTMLElement like `div`,which must both has the real `height` and `width` properties that make the `background-color` works.

Why this difference between `body, html` and `div`?

I think,

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}
```

is the only way to make the whole screen background color.

Comment: Html tag (or body) by default doesnt have any real hight. Div wont have a real height either only if it has content. The solution is indeed to force the html/body to have 100% height/width. Better to use it on body then on html i think.

Comment: I don't quite understand what is the problem? What are you trying to achieve? Please create [mcve] of the problem you are facing. If you use background-color for html-element the whole page will have that color: https://jsfiddle.net/wwjtx6yy/

Comment: the background-color worked well with the html tag which doesn't have real height. But if a div doesn't have a real height, the background-color doesn't work.

Comment: Provide an example where it is not working as desired.

Comment: well, since a div is a block element by default it has a height of zero. Without defining a size a putting some content into it (and thereby implicitely giving it a non-zero height), it will stay the same and appear to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no difference between html, body, or div element regarding their presentation.
like html and body, div height and width is not set to anything by default. If you don't set it yourself and if there is no content inside it, you won't be able to see its background color.

example:

```css
.empty{
   background-color: black; 
}

.size-set{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;  
}


.content-div{
   background-color: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<div class="empty"></div>

<div class="size-set"></div>

<div class="content-div">content is here</div>
```

I hope this will clear some of your doubts.